# Injection? $f(x)=3x-\ \mid x \mid + \mid x-2 \mid$

Tags: number-theory

For the function how do I tell if it's injective or not?  There's two absolute value signs and is confusing me!

$$f(x)=3x\ - |x| + |x-2|$$

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT** Cut 
$\mathbb{R}$ into three interval where you know the the sing of 
$|x|$
and
$|x-2|$

In that way in each interval the function would be affine(i.e. a line)
therefore you would know the $\max$ and $\min$ value of $f$ in each of these intervals.

If  the values $f$ take in each interval overlap then the function would not be injective otherwise it will.

Comment: Ok I got it!  How do I find the inverse for this?  Just curious

Comment: @computer.nerd if you have a function which is defined with multiple brances and you can find the inverse in each interval then the inverce function would be defined also in braches the braches you found in each interval. And then you will have found the rule which defines your inverve function i.e. $f^{-1}(y)=x \forall y \in \mathrm{Im}f$